# HTML Canvas, Polygons are connected each other

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, polygon

I am trying to generating multiple polygon from a quite large `json` file. The polygon should separate each other, but it somehow connected each other.

[image: polygons]

I am building it in next.js.

Here are the codes:

`Canvas.tsx`

```
// ../components/Canvas.tsx

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

const Canvas = props => {
  
  const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas: any = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000'
    context.beginPath()
    { props.x.map((pointx, i) => context.lineTo(0.25 * pointx, 0.25 * props.y[i])) } // I scaled it to 0.25 (25% original size)
    context.closePath()
    context.fill()
  }, [])
  
  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} width={props.width} height={props.height} style={{ zIndex: 20, position: 'absolute', objectFit: 'contain' }}/>
}

export default Canvas
```

`index.tsx`

```
import React, { ReactElement, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import data from '../public/11_regions-copy.json'
import Canvas from '../components/Canvas';


export const getServerSideProps = async () => {

  let xTemp: any[] = []
  let yTemp: any[] = []

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
    xTemp.push(data[i].all_points_x)
    yTemp.push(data[i].all_points_y)
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < Object.keys(data).length; j++) {
    let xArray = xTemp[j]
    xArray.push(xArray[0])

    let yArray = yTemp[j]
    yArray.push(yArray[0])
  }
  
  let x = [].concat.apply([], xTemp);
  let y = [].concat.apply([], yTemp);


  return {
    props: {
      x,
      y
    },
  }
}

function Home({ x, y, xTemp1, yTemp1 }: any): ReactElement {

  return (
    <div>
      <Canvas width={1680} height={756} x={x} y={y} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

the `json` file:
[json](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/files/7167202/11_regions-copy.json.zip)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *error* results as a consequence of you *merging* all regions from your data source into one long path. This happens in `getServerSideProps` (which is a bit *clunky* btw.).

So, your data looks like this:

```
{
    "0": {

        "all_points_x": [ ... ],
        "all_points_y": [ ... ]
    },
    "1": {
        "all_points_x": [ ... ],
        "all_points_y": [ ... ]
    },
    // ...
}
```

Your `getServerSideProps` makes this:

```
{
    props: {
        x: [ ... ],
        y: [ ... ],
    }
}
```

Which you then draw as one long path here:

```
context.beginPath()
{ props.x.map((pointx, i) => context.lineTo(0.25 * pointx, 0.25 * props.y[i])) }
context.closePath()
context.fill()
```

---

If you stop doing that, and simply draw each *region* as a separate path, you'll get what you want:

```javascript
// here `data` would be something like:
// const data = await (await fetch('11_regions-copy.json')).json();

Object.values(data).forEach(({all_points_x: x, all_points_y: y}) => {
  ctx.beginPath();

  x.forEach((x, i) => {
    ctx.lineTo(0.25 * x, 0.25 * y[i]);
  });

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
});
```

[image]

---

With regards to Kaiido's comment, you might consider drawing one path, by utilizing [`moveTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/moveTo)

```javascript
ctx.beginPath();

Object.values(data).forEach(({all_points_x: x, all_points_y: y}) => {
  ctx.moveTo(0.25 * x[0], 0.25 * y[0]);

  x.forEach((x, i) => {
    ctx.lineTo(0.25 * x, 0.25 * y[i]);
  });
});

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: @Kaiido True, maybe. Though in some way the regions must be separated. If this happens by drawing them individually or as a long path with the help of `moveTo` can be considered. Though both ways are impossible as long as the regions are merged like they currently are.

Comment: Not "maybe", painting multiple simple shapes is always slower than painting a single more complex one. And I don't understand the rest of your comment.

Comment: Ok yes, obviously you're correct in this regards. My *maybe* is with regards to whether this would actually be a problem for the OP, for as it stands there's only very few regions. // The rest of my comment is with regards to the actual problem in this question. The OP *merges* all regions into one big *region*, thereby losing all information about where a region starts and ends.

Comment: "The OP merges all regions into one big region, thereby losing all information about where a region starts and ends." I don't see where in the question it's been alluded that this is an issue to them.

Comment: Have you read my answer then? I'm basically guiding the reader/OP through it? And using the exact code in the question in a test project also yields the exact same problematic output as in the question.

Comment: Yes I did read it, I still don't see a "problem" with merging all the sub-paths to a single path, nor why "losing all information about where a region starts and ends" is an issue at all.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I am accepting @Yoshi 's answer since it doesn't require changing in the data source format.

Comment: @hisam mine either, I just made a dataset easier to put in the snippet. You can very well just move to the first point using your dataset

Comment: @Kaiido Ok, suppose `data` in your answer wasn't of type `Array<Array<number, number>>`, but rather `Array<number, number>`, how would you know when to `moveTo`? This is what's happening in the question. (please excuse my pseudo type)

Comment: Ok, now I see better.